# Let $a>0$, show that $\sum(1+a^n)^{-1}$ is divergent if $0<a\leq1$ and convergent if $a>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

> Let $a>0$, show that $\sum(1+a^n)^{-1}$ is divergent if $0<a\leq1$ and convergent if $a>1.$

**What I did:**

If $0<a\leq1$, then $(1+a^n)^{-1}\geq 1/2$, so the series is divergent. Similarly for $a>1$, $(1+a^n)^{-1}<a^{-n}$, so the series is convergent.

The problem is I don't like this reasoning, seems not so rigorous to me. How can I improve this? Any suggestion please. Thanks.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks for pointing out. It was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious with *equivalents*: it's a series with positive terms and
$$(1+a^n)^{-1}\sim_\infty\begin{cases}1&\text{if}\enspace 0<a<1,\\[0.5ex]\dfrac12 &\text{if}\enspace a=1,\\[0.51ex]\dfrac1{a^n} &\text{if}\enspace a>=1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?